World cup cards avoiding hard-to-get football teams
I open a cereal box every day. The cereal box contains a card of one of the teams playing the World Cup - and there are $n$ teams playing. The card each day is a random draw from all possible sets of cards. The question of how many days have to pass until I have collected all cars at least once is called the coupon collector problem and the answer is $n H_n$, where $H_n$ is the $n$-th Harmonic number.
Now, once I have collected all the cards, there are some which I got only once. For example, the last card which I collected among them all. I call these singletons (or $S$). It is known that there are in general $H_n$ singleton cards.
I am angry with these cards - they made the whole collection process take longer! In retrospect, I wonder if I look back at the number of days that it took me to get all $n$ cards, how many days would I need to collect all non-singleton cards at least once?
Simulations help to guess the answer: for $n=100$, it takes 523 days to get all cards, but I could have gotten all non-singleton cards in only 384 days. My first question is: what is the general expression for how long it would take me to collect all non-singleton cards at least once?
I thought the answer could be $n[H_n-H_{H_n}]$, which is how long it takes me to get $n-H_n$ cards from a total of $n$ cards (see the formula here). Unfortunately, this number is too low (for $n=100$ it gives 287).
My second question is about the number of singletons, which as I've said, is known to be $H_n$. Suppose that I take the shortest subsequence of card-draws to obtain all non-singleton cards at least once. For example, if coupons are integers from 1 to 7, one sequence of drawing them could be
 1     3     2     2     7     7     1     3     4     5     5     2     5     2     3     6

The singleton coupons are 4 and 6, and the shortest subsequence to obtain all non-singleton coupons at least once is
 1     3     2     2     7     7     1     3     5

In this subsequence, I am interested in the average number of new singleton cards. In this example, this is only 5. As before, simulations provide a preliminary answer. For $n=100$, we obtain 5 singleton coupons in the first round, as expected, but in the second round we obtain more singleton cards: 7.4! My second question is: can we figure out how many singleton cards there are in the second round?
I thought that, if in the second round we have $n-H_n$ World Cup teams, we could apply the argument recursively to conclude that the number of singleton cards in the second round equals $H_{n-H_n}$, but this is incorrect as the simulation results show.
I have been thinking about this problem but I haven't found a way forward. Any hints/ideas would be most appreciated.

At various points you talk about a random variable as if it were a constant - e.g. the number of days until you collect all cards is a random variable, not constant, which is known to have mean $n H_n$.
